# How to get the sum of some specific column values in a matrix table

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix table that displays corresponding amount for each Scheduled date in the dataset.

[image]

I placed a filter on the table that would determine the schedule dates displayed as specified by the user using parameters. But the issue is with the "Due Date". From the attached table, I only want to sum up amounts that fall under dates from 13th oct to 5th Dec for each row as those are the only due dates. But It keeps summing up the entire amounts in the row.

Any Ideas how I can achieve this.

I have tried using the expression below but it's not giving the desired result

```
Sum(iif(cdate(today) >= Fields!scheduledateValue.Value, Fields!amountValue.Value,0))
```

It's summing all the values.

Comment: Can you please add your code that shows what is happening so far?

Comment: It looks like it should work. Is ScheduledDateValue a Date or string? Maybe use the CDate around it too.

Comment: @StayOnTarget it's actually a ssrs report, that's about the only code I've written so far

Comment: @HannoverFist ScheduledDateValue is a date. I would try using the cdate() function as well. Thanks